# How to have one button on right and two inputs on left to fill the line?

Tags: html, css, input, css-float, width

I found several similar posts, but not a solution for this problem. I'm trying to do this:

```
| +---------------------+ +---------------------+ +------------------------------+ |
| |        Input        | |        Input        | |             Button           | |
| | 50% remaining width | | 50% remaining width | | fixed width based on content | |
| +---------------------+ +---------------------+ +------------------------------+ |
```

- two input fields and a button on the same line (the screen width, not fixed)
- the button floats on the right (with the size dependent on the content, not fixed)
- the two input fields float on the left (filling the rest of the line 50% each one)
- instead when the screen width is less than a defined minimum, these 3 elements fill a line each one

I tried several codes, but I cannot find a working and responsive solution. This is the better (but still not correct) solution I made:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

.container {width: 100%; display:table;}
.left-side{display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle}
.left-side .fields {width: 100%;}
.form-control {width: 49%}
.right-side {float:right}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="fields">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <button type="submit" class="">Search</button>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Maybe there are better ways to do it. Could you help me? Thanks!

Comment: This is too broad... It involves not only the placement (which is not hard, byt the way) but the media queries to make it responsive... Narrow your question down by showing some of your effort. As it is, it's more like a code-for-me question...

Comment: "I tried several codes". Please post that so we can see what you have and what you tried.

Comment: I modified the first post (sorry, I'm new here).

Answer (score 0):

Even this is pretty old topic, I tried to make a solution. Left side with inputs is maximized (100% width) `table-cell`, right side `table-cell` with undefined length. Content of both table cells with `nowrap`.

Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpavel76/hL5ggv4L/